# RPi Google Calendar Refresh

Tags: pi-3

Making a Google Calendar week view in a picture frame. followed nice project with exactly what I need. **only issue is the calendar is loaded in Chromium browser on pi and doesn't refresh so that changes to calendar are updated**. here is project and code: http://www.deviceplus.com/how-tos/raspberrypi-guide/diy-smart-picture-frame-calendar-using-raspberry-pi-3-part-1/

Setup Chromium Browser:

1) `sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`    #open autostart file

I. Add the following line to the end of the file:

`@/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerordialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk` #open Chromium browser without error messages or dialog disabling crash bubbles and info bar in kiosk (full screen) mode

II. Exit & Save by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> for Yes, and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write the file.

2) `sudo apt-get install unclutter`   #to install program that removes the mouse cursor while in fullscreen mode

3) `sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`   #open autostart file

I. Add the following line to the end of the file `@unclutter -idle 0.1 -root`

II. Exit & Save by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> for Yes, and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I have found to set a refresh clock would be to make use of a plug-in like this one.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403866/raspberry-pi-refresh-browser

Run a cron job to do a refresh, there's a modification to refresh.sh required, the answer is given but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that. I had found a plug-in for chromium to refresh as set intervals but it needs to be set up every time the browser starts. I’m running this on a headless setup.